# How to display a centered wall of divs with CSS?

Tags: css, css-float

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS Appropriate Way to Center Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722648/css-appropriate-way-to-center-content)

My goal is to display a wall of pictures using CSS (not tables).

I would like the pictures **to be aligned on center of the container**

`wallElement` should have `320px` width and `240px` height.

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%">
  <div style="width:320px;height:240px">MyPicture1</div>
  <div style="width:320px;height:240px">MyPicture2</div>
</div>
```

I tried with `display:inline-block;` with no luck.
I had success with `float: left;` BUT wall elements are not centered.

Comment: What was wrong with inline-block, exactly? And how many elements do you want on each row?

Answer (score 0):

`inline-block` will provide the solution you requested.

Here's a working example of how this can be accomplished: http://jsfiddle.net/2BHTH/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="Container">
 <div class="picture">MyPicture1</div>
 <div class="picture">MyPicture2</div>
 <div class="picture">MyPicture3</div>
 <div class="picture">MyPicture4</div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
body { 
    width:95%;
    margin: 0 auto;        
}

#Container {
    padding:.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#eee;
}

div.picture {
    width:320px;
    height:240px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: .5em;
    background-color:#ccc;
}​
```